# SQL Inner Join 2 Tables

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

Hoping to get some help with this, I have made a few attempts at an inner join that shows all 'Product' information from the product table for, any product that has sold more than 10 units using an inner join.

```
PRODUCT TABLE (Columns)
P_CODE, P_DESCRIPT, P_INDATE, P_QOH, P_MIN, P_PRICE, P_DISCOUNT, V_CODE

LINE TABLE (Columns) this table shows the lines/information for each 
invoice

INV_NUMBER, LINE NUMBER, P_CODE, LINE_UNITS, LINE_PRICE, LINE_TOTAL
```

I understand that I have to make the join using the common key attribute (p_code) but I cannot figure out how to do the sum within the inner join.

Here is my most recent attempt:

```
SELECT * PRODUCT FROM PRODUCT
INNER JOIN line
ON product.p_code = line.p_code
WHERE sum(line_units) >=10
AND line.p_code = product.p_code;
```

Error: near "product"; syntax error

Any help would be appreciated, 
Thank you.

Comment: Should read 10> not 10>= and most likely the 'from product' is redundant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have the table name `PRODUCT` within the `SELECT` section. And the `sum()` needs to happen within the `SELECT` section along with the extra `HAVING` clause at the end.

```
SELECT *, sum(line_units) as line_units_sum FROM product
INNER JOIN line ON product.p_code = line.p_code
WHERE line.p_code = product.p_code
HAVING line_units_sum >= 10
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the initial error but now I am receiving one for my sum function " Error: misuse of aggregate function sum() "

Comment: Sorry about that - actually mocked up the tables and re-ran the query locally. I updated the query so it should work now.

Comment: Was able to get exactly what I wanted with a few amendments to your query. Added in 'group by product.p_code' also removed * from the select and manually entered in the product attributes I wanted to show or else it displayed ALL attributes from both Product & Line, which I assume is because the tables are both now joined resulting in the '*' in the select statement showing both product and line attributes? - appreciate the help John.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It's pulling in all the fields from both tables because of the `*` in the SELECT. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

### The requirement

> Show all product information from the `product` table for any product that has sold more than 10 units.

### The solution

Because you only want to build the projection from the `product` table, and you don't need any column from the `line` table, you can also use a correlated subquery like the following one:

```
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE 10 < (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM line
    WHERE line.p_code = product.p_code
)
```

The database optimizer might choose to use a JOIN internally if the cost of the JOIN is lower than other alternatives. So, it does not mean that the query will do row-by-row processing for the outer table records. Only the execution plan can tell how the query is executed by the database engine.